# Nested query using while condition - sql

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

I need to do a nested query on a single table. Each row is potentially the parent or child of another row.

Is it possible to do this with a single select statement? Ive started using this statement but it only goes down one level.

```
select * from myTable where parent_id in 
   (select id from myTable where name = 'manager' )
```

This select however will only go down one level. If a row has multiple children they will be ignored. (In the table each row has an **Id** field , if a row has a parent then the parents **Id** value will be in the child's **parent_Id** field. )

If i could include a while loop in the SQL which would always check to see if the returned **Id** was a parent or not and if it was check and see if any other row was its child by checking the other rows **parent_Id**. However i m concerned this would take alot of cycles to eventually find all parent child relationships. Any suggestions? Thanks

using Oracle db

Comment: Which DB are using? Different DB's have different solutions for this particular problem.

Comment: Could you give an example of a query you are trying to write - what fields you want returned for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a hierarchical query like this:

```
select * from mytable
connect by prior id = parent_id
start with name = 'Manager';
```

(A "nested table" is something else entirely.)

Comment: I'm going to assume that this is Oracle specific code for dealing with Hierarchies. SQL Server of course has its own methods. For a more generic approaches, check out http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Kaufmann-Management-Systems/dp/1558609202/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1306168577&sr=8-3

Comment: @Tom, correct this is an Oracle-specific answer; the question is tagged for Oracle.

Comment: Thank you, this query will dive into every parent child relationship where it finds a value of "Manager" in a field named name, therefore if the value is not unique then i will start to see lots of duplicates. Thanks